# exchange 2007 - non email users in the GAL

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007, exchange

We have a fairly new Exchange 2007 SP2 install with some GAL issues - basically when you browse the GAL from Outlook 2007 there are users listed that are not email users.

If you look in Exchange under recipient configuration these users don't exist. They're AD users, but were never configured in Exchange, yet for some reason they show up in the GAL. The GAL seems to update correctly if new users are added or existing accounts are modified.

I was wondering if anyone had any insight on this? I have other Exchange 2007 installs that are fine and don't have this issue. This install was completely clean, no migration or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with this a bit more the following command resolved the issue:

```
Update-GlobalAddressList - Identity "address list" -DomainController "domain controller name"
```

The GAL is now correctly displaying for everyone

Answer (score 2):

If you open Active Directory Users and Computers do those users have an "Exchange Advanced" tab?

If so try checking the box to "Hide from Exchange address lists" if you don't want them to show.

Comment: The 'Exchange Advanced' tab only shows up if the Exchange 2003 administration tools are installed on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that these AD Users have email addresses configured on the user object, independent of Exchange. Importing them into Exchange overwrites this value, which would explain the behavior you're seeing. This would manifest as looking at the user in ADU&C and they have a listed email address, but the user doesn't show up in the Exchange 2007 Console. The quick test is to remove that address in ADU&C and wait for a GAL sync to see if they disappear.

Comment: If I open up ADU&C and check the properties on one of the problematic users there is no email address configured - we also verified that they are not a member of any distribution groups.